# Is it possible to use New Relic with GAE/J?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, newrelic

Is there a way to run New Relic Server Monitor with Google App Engine for Java?

[New Relic docs](https://newrelic.com/docs/python/status-of-python-agent) say that Python GAE is not supported , but there is no mention of GAE/J.
GAE/J uses modified Jetty, which is supported by New Relic, but I was not able to make it work the standard way and I haven't found any information about the matter anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Doesn't new relic require you to add an agent to the system? You don't have any access to the actual "server" in GAE. It's all virtual and managed by them. I would recommend if you want to monitor your site for uptime signing up for something like pingdom which will alert you if your site stops responding.

Comment: I does. I was wondering if I could somehow deploy the agent along with the app. Is that complete nonsense? :) I'm interested in profiling capabilities of New Relic, but of course, there are other options.

Comment: To be able to use the Java app monitoring agent, you have to be able to pass the `-javaagent` option to the JVM and I'm pretty sure GAE won't allow it. To get Server Monitoring, you have to be able to install and run a daemon process. I believe GAE won't allow that, either.

Comment: No. GAE is a black box. More akin to Heroku than to AWS. You have no access to the JVM or the server itself.

Comment: I wrote to the New Relic support and they responded that it is indeed not possible to use New Relic on GAE/J